# input of data in a FILE

Tags: c, codeblocks

i have to input the data into a FILE * (this is in C and using codeblocks), the data is a struct containing 3 char[ ] an 1 double, i dont know why when i print the file it repeats the last struct twice and in "dni" it puts 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char dni[9];
    char nombre[100], apellido[100];
    double monto_adeudado;
} t_datos;

void carga_del_archivo(char[]);
t_datos carga_struct(t_datos);

int main()
{
    char nombrearchivo[30];
    printf("ingrese el nombre del archivo: ");
    gets(nombrearchivo);
    carga_del_archivo(nombrearchivo);
    return 0;
}

void carga_del_archivo(char nombre[30])
{
    FILE* ptrarch;
    t_datos aux;
    ptrarch = fopen(nombre, "ab");
    if (ptrarch != NULL) {
        do {
            aux = carga_struct(aux);
            fwrite(&aux, sizeof(t_datos), 1, ptrarch);
        } while (strcmp(aux.dni, "0") != 0);
    } else {
        printf("ERROR\n");
    }
}

t_datos carga_struct(t_datos aux)
{
    printf("\ningrese el dni: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(aux.dni);
    if (strcmp(aux.dni, "0") == 0)
        return aux;
    printf("\ningrese el nombre: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(aux.nombre);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\ningrese el apellido: ");
    gets(aux.apellido);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\ningrese el monto adeudado: ");
    scanf("%lf", &aux.monto_adeudado);
    return aux;
}
```

Comment: `gets()` --> `fgets()`.

Comment: remove `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: since `fflush(stdin);` causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Note that if you expect the file to be readable on a different machine, you should use some serialization (e.g. write the strings separately to avoid padding bytes being written and use a textual representation for the double (`%a` with C99 or better, `%e` otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
       {
        aux=carga_struct(aux);
        fwrite(&aux,sizeof(t_datos),1,ptrarch);
       }while(strcmp(aux.dni,"0")!=0);
```

When you enter `0` here `aux=carga_struct(aux)` you write it to the disk by `fwrite` on next line before checking this statement: `while(strcmp(aux.dni,"0")!=0)`.

Comment: changed it to this, works better but still repeats the last        
        aux=carga_struct(aux);
        while(strcmp(aux.dni,"0")!=0)
        {
              fwrite(&aux,sizeof(t_datos),1,ptrarch);
              aux=carga_struct(aux)             
        }